# shortest path MST

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a undirected graph and $w:E\rightarrow \mathbb R$ a weight function.
If the shortest path between two adjacent vertices is the connecting edge then there is a minimum-spanning tree containing this edge.
I think this is true but how can I prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}
V&=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}\\
E&=\{\{v_1,v_2\},\{v_2,v_3\},\{v_1,v_3\}\}\\
w(\{v_1,v_2\})&=3\\
w(\{v_2,v_3\})&=w(\{v_1,v_3\})\\
&=2\ .
\end{align}
What is the shortest path between vertices $\ v_1\ $ and $\ v_2\ $ in this weighted graph? What are its minimal spanning trees?